# dynamic concatenation of columns for finding max

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my data -

```
ID,Pay1,Pay2,Pay3,Low,High,expected_output
1,12,21,23,1,2,21
2,21,34,54,1,3,54
3,74,56,76,1,1,74
```

The goal is to calculate the max `Pay` of each row as per the `Pay` column index specified in `Low` and `High` columns.

For example, for row 1, calculate the `max` of `Pay1` and `Pay2` columns as `Low` and `High` are 1 and 2.

I have tried building a dynamic string and then using `eval` function which is not performing well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is filter only `Pay` columns and then using numpy broadcasting select columns by `Low` and `High` columns, pass to [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and last get `max`:

```
df1 = df.filter(like='Pay')

m1  = np.arange(len(df1.columns)) >= df['Low'].to_numpy()[:, None] - 1
m2  = np.arange(len(df1.columns)) <= df['High'].to_numpy()[:, None] - 1

df['expected_output'] = df1.where(m1 & m2, 0).max(axis=1)
print (df)
   ID  Pay1  Pay2  Pay3  Low  High  expected_output
0   1    12    21    23    1     2               21
1   2    21    34    54    1     3               54
2   3    74    56    76    1     1               74
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! Brought down the exec from 13seconds to 64ms on a sample of 12K rows!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative; I expect @jezrael's solution to be faster as it is within numpy and `pd.wide_to_long` is not particularly fast:

```
grouping = (
    pd.wide_to_long(df.filter(regex="^Pay|Low|High"), 
                   i=["Low", "High"], 
                   stubnames="Pay", 
                   j="num")
    .query("Low==num or High==num")
    .groupby(level=["Low", "High"])
    .Pay.max()
)

grouping

Low  High
1    1       74
     2       21
     3       54
Name: Pay, dtype: int64


df.join(grouping.rename("expected_output"), on=["Low", "High"])

    ID  Pay1    Pay2    Pay3    Low     High    expected_output
0   1   12  21  23  1   2   21
1   2   21  34  54  1   3   54
2   3   74  56  76  1   1   74
```